# How do you write German text into a CSV file?

Tags: python, selenium, file, web-scraping, utf

I'm trying to write text that was scraped from a German website into a CSV file. I tried using UTF-8 encoding as such:

`with open('/Users/filepath/result.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:`
    `f.write(text)`

But this is what appeared in the CSV file instead of with an ü:

`Projekt fÃ¼r Alleinerziehende mit mehreren (behinderten) Kindern`

Comment: How did you check the result? Can you give the hexadecimal representation of the data that is stored?

Comment: I think it should be ‘utf-8’ instead ‘utf8’.

Comment: @Muzzamil Most encodings have several aliases. Using a completely unknown one would result in a `LookupError`.

Comment: @Muzzamil I tried both of them, same result.

Comment: @Klaus D. 50:72:6f:6a:65:6b:74:20:66:fc:72:20:41:6c:6c:65:69:6e:65:72:7a:69:65:68:65:6e:64:65:20:6d:69:74:20:6d:65:68:72:65:72:65:6e:20:28:62:65:68:69:6e:64:65:72:74:65:6e:29:20:4b:69:6e:64:65:72:6e

Comment: @JustinBurack add attribute `ensure_ascii=False` when you write file.

Comment: you may want to write a byte-order-marker (aka "BOM") when writing the file.  The file that opens/displays it will have to guess otherwise...: looks like Python has, "encodings.utf_8_sig": https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ISO-8859-15 encoding. Also make sure that when you open the file in an editor, it's encoding is set to same encoding.