# Support german translation in export csv in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the german translation on my website and I want to export data in CSV . Unfortunately it prints this "â€ErnÃ¤hrungssouverÃ¤nitÃ¤t" instead of the german character "Ernährungssouveränität".
what can I do?
I tested utf-8 but it didn't work.

```
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv", charset="utf-8")
```

Comment: as answer that we have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59921966/7618968) you should use ISO-8859-15 instead of utf-8

Comment: @SaeedRamezani how can use that? should i replace it with charset="utf-8" ?

Comment: it didn't work that way